# Virgo Nano - OSGi Bundle sample

Tags: raspberry-pi, osgi-bundle, eclipse-virgo

I'm tring to get a rest service running in my raspberry pi with Virgo Nano application server.

I was googling for sample code for OSGi bundle for rest service so I can play with the code and write my own rest service. But there were no specific sample for Virgo Nano.

Can some one can point me to a good sample.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that Virgo Nano doesn't include servlet container such as Tomcat or Jetty so you will need the HttpService to bind your REST services. You can try with OSGI JAX-RS Connector from EclipseSource. Check here http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2012/01/23/an-osgi-jax-rs-connector-part-1-publishing-rest-services/